# Unable to update Galaxy S3 Android after flashing CWM

Tags: rooting, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, recovery-mode

I just unboxed a Samsung Galaxy S3 and immediately, before first boot, rooted it installing CWM Recovery and SuperSU. I found it to be not the best idea, becuase I forgot to launch the Samsung update to 4.1.

In fact, stock upgrade does reboot the phone into recovery but then CWM says the signature is invalid, etc. I should have done all this in inverse order (first stock upgrade, then root).

The question is: how can I upgrade this Galaxy to stock JB?

Idea: restoring the original recovery... but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.android.gs/restore-samsung-galaxy-s3-i9300-to-android-4-0-4-ics-xxalf2-stock-firmware/) gives a nice step by step tutorial on how to re-flash to stock ICS, which will relash the stock recovery.

In a nutshell:

> How to restore Galaxy S3 to Android 4.0.4 ICS XXLAF2 stock firmware:
>
> 1. Download the ICS stock firmware file from [here](http://www.hotfile.com/dl/161114096/469a480/I9300XXALF2_I9300ODDALF1_INU.zip.html)
>      or [here](http://ifile.it/8lyz79u).
> 2. After the ROM file is downloaded successfully, you should extract its contents and you will get a single file with the ‘.tar.md5′
>      extension. Save it on your computer’s desktop.
> 3. Download Odin3 3.o4 for Galaxy S3 I9300 from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?189h7dqldccnrq8).
> 4. Extract Odin.zip contents into a single folder and save it on your PC desktop.
> 5. Now, power OFF your Galaxy S3 phone and after this you will need to boot into download mode.
> 6. Boot into download mode by pressing ‘volume down’ + ‘home’ + ‘Power’ and release these buttons only after the display powers ON.
>      Press Volume Up button to confirm that you want to load download mode.
> 7. Now, go to your PC and launch the ‘Odin’ executable file. The one you’ve extracted at step 4.
> 8. Next, connect your SGS3 I9300 to your computer and ODIN should display a message box saying ‘added!!’. If you don’t see this message
>      then it means that the USB drivers aren’t installed on your PC and you
>      should use the download links in the preparation guide, the ones
>      listed above this tutorial guide. If Odin did find the Samsung USB
>      Driver you’re free to move to the next step.
> 9. In Odin click the button that is called ‘PDA’.
> 10. Find the file you’ve extracted at step 2. It should have the ‘.tar.md5′ extension. Select it and it will be loaded into Odin. NOTE:
>       Don’t change any of the Odin’s default settings and make sure that the
>       ‘re-partition’ option isn’t selected.
> 11. Press the START button in ODIN and the program will now begin to install the stock firmware files. When the installation is complete
>       you will see a ‘PASS’ alert displayed by Odin and this means that
>       everything went according to plan. Your phone will also restart and
>       after the Samsung Logo appears you are free to unplug the device from
>       your computer. NOTE: If Odin gets stuck you are required to disconnect
>       the phone from your PC and remove its battery and then re-insert it
>       and, now repeat all the entire tutorial once again as something went
>       wrong and the firmware wasn’t flashed.
> 12. That should do it, now your phone has been restored to factory stock firmware. Make sure to use the comments section in case you
>       other questions.